# Open a New tab From iframe javascript event without pop up block

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a iframe in a page.

After i successfully send data to server within iframe, the server responds with next URL to open ,  i want to open the next URL in a **new tab** or in the parent window.

The **Problem** i am facing is, the browser treats it as a popup and blocks it.
In chrome it is treated as pop up and in safari it doesn't do anything.

The iframe is pointing to [iframe](http://payment.netforce.co.th) (written in REACT)
The parent URL is [main page](http://netforce.co.th/pricing/).

Here is the part of the code that s causing error.

```
            this.props.dispatch(actions.init_db(vals, (error,data)=>{
                this.setState({loading:false})
                if(error){
                    this.setState({error:error});
                }else{
                    url=data.next_url;
                    var win=window.open(url);
                    win.focus();
                 }
           }));
```

Basically actions.init_db() calls an ajax function that writes the value to the server.

The server than responds with error or data.If no errror, the data contains Next URL and i want to open the URL.

Any Suggestion or alternate to this solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you call `window.open` from code that isn't running in direct response to a user action (such as a click), it's likely to get blocked by the popup blocker of the browser. The solution is to make sure you're running that code in direct response to a user action. So for instance, when you have the URL from the server, show a div on the page with the link in it for the user to open themselves.